# CS0121 The call is ambiguous between 'Task.Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>)' and 'Task.Run(Func<Task>)'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have the error happening at `GetFlowTask = Task.Run(func.Invoke);`.

He context is the following:

```
public Task<string> GetFlowTask { get; set; }
```

And the faulty line is inside a function:

```
protected void PushTask(Func<string> func)
{
    GetFlowTask = Task.Run(func.Invoke);
}
```

I did not have this error until recently (I believe a VS 2017 update).

Furthermore I have not idea how to lift the ambiguity. Any hint ?

And why Roslyn is not picking `Task.Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>)` in the first place ?

Comment: Fresh Visual Studio 2017 compiles your example just fine. https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgbgpgTglgZgTwDQBMQGoA+ABADAAmwEYBuAWACg9CiBWcqgZkICZ8BhSgb0vz8ObYAbAB5iuAHz4A4hGAAxADYB7AO7D8XfAHM5JfAGc9+AL6Ve/AA5RlwCAGM7KQgBZ8ABQCuBgBbCAFNi0YkSS+HCeAHb2AJQWfDwU/MkyckpqGgC8hEIAdABKUf4R0bkAkpFgygDWEDEMyWYUJkA==. Could you please provide a minimal ready-to-paste example, reproducing the problem at your side?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? The code you've provided (`public Task<string> GetFlowTask { get; set; } protected void PushTask(Func<string> func) { this.GetFlowTask = Task.Run(func.Invoke); }`) works just fine. So you must have some other code causing the issue.

Comment: Here, with VS2017 15.9.7 (and resharper 2018.3.3) I have the error. I updated the function so it's complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the compiler doesn't correctly infer the type for `func.Invoke` passed as a parameter.

```
GetFlowTask = Task.Run(func.Invoke);
//Fails in 15.9.7 (but works in LINQPad v5.36.03)
```

But there are easy alternatives.

```
GetFlowTask = Task.Run(func); //Succeeds
GetFlowTask = Task.Run(() => func.Invoke()); //Succeeds
```